# How do I interact with Google Docs (Sheets) from another scripting environment (VB.net within Grasshopper3d)?

Tags: google-docs-api, grasshopper

I'm scripting with VB.net (and sometimes with c#) within Grasshopper (a plug-in for a 3d modeling program called Rhino), and I'd like to interact with Google Docs, specifically with the spreadsheet app.

I want to be able to send data from Grasshopper to populate google spreadsheets.
The data is always either numerical or string.
I'd also like to generate charts from the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this at the bottom of [this thread](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/python-error-importing-pyexpat) on the GH website.

.. And this is a solution for *reading* that should work in python as to use c# would need you to use other libraries.

You need to publish the spreadsheet as a csv first.

```
import urllib2
myUrl="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AgIWT_wqd-VmdE1NekRSWFZoUnBQdWJhYUhwcU1vclE&single=true&gid=0&output=csv"
response = urllib2.urlopen(myUrl)
print response.read()
```

[Here's a working GH implementation](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8064971/GHdemo/getCSVfromGoogle.gh)

[*this should probably be a comment, but I can't comment yet*]